# Find the angle $x$ made by the median of some triangle.

Tags: geometry

I had no idea, I've tried to use half area and other stuffs to answer the following.

**Exercise.** Let $\triangle\, ABC$ a triangle with angles $\angle ABC = 106^{\circ}$ and $\angle ACB = 23 ^{\circ}$. Let $M$ the mid point of $BC$. Find $x=\angle MAC$.

Comment: Please provide a figure.

Comment: you can use the sine rule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Let the diameter of the circumscribed circle be
$2R=1$. Then all the sizes of the sides can be calculated as

\begin{align} 
|AB|&=\sin23^\circ
,\\
|AC|&=\sin106^\circ
,\\
|BC|&=\sin51^\circ
,\\
|MB|=|MC|&=\tfrac12\,\sin51^\circ
.
\end{align}

Now we can use the cosine rule to get $|AM|$
and use it again 
to get $\cos\angle MAC$.

---

**Edit:**

Using cosine rule for $\triangle AMC$ we get 
the unknown side $|AM|$

\begin{align} 
|AM|&=\sqrt{|AC|^2+|MC|^2-2\,|AC|\,|MC|\cos23^\circ}
,\\
\end{align}

Using cosine rule again we get 
the unknown side $|AM|$

\begin{align} 
\cos\angle MAC&=
\frac{|AM|^2+|AC|^2-|MC|^2}{2\,|AM|\,|AC|}
,\\
\angle MAC&=\arccos\left(
\frac{|AM|^2+|AC|^2-|MC|^2}{2\,|AM|\,|AC|}
\right)
.
\end{align}

Substitution of the values of $|AM|,|AC|,|MC|$
gives
$\cos\angle MAC\approx 14.12^\circ$.